# Getting location and assigning to global variable

Tags: android

Ok I have global variable `lat` and `lon` initialized with `0.0` and I am using fusedLocationProvider to get `lat` and `lon` and use those value in the retrofit.
But the problem here is the code which deals with retrofit is called first so the `lat` and `lon` with `0.0` is used and the code with fetch actual location is called after the retrofit.

I tried by keeping the code to get an actual location in `onStart()` but still it didn't work.

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
private var lon: Double = 0.0
private var lat: Double = 0.0


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location ->
        lon = location.longitude
        lat = location.latitude
        Log.e("MainActivity","1st one $lon $lat")
    }


    retroInstance = RetroInstance()
    val instance = retroInstance.getInstane()
    val api = instance.create(RetroInterface::class.java)
    val call = api.getWeather(lat.toString(), lon.toString(), appid)
    Log.e("MainActivity","2nd one $lon $lat")   
}
```

I expect `Log.e("MainActivity","1st one $lon $lat")` to be executed first but `Log.e("MainActivity","2nd one $lon $lat")` is executed first

Comment: Call retrofit inside **addOnSuccessListener**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the callback of the locationListener and after getting the callback you can post data to Retrofit.

```
  fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location ->
        lon = location.longitude
        lat = location.latitude
        Log.e("MainActivity","1st one $lon $lat")

          retroInstance = RetroInstance()
          val instance = retroInstance.getInstane()
          val api = instance.create(RetroInterface::class.java)
          val call = api.getWeather(lat.toString(), lon.toString(), appid)
          Log.e("MainActivity","2nd one $lon $lat") 
    }
```

Comment: @dreamprojects because getting the location (lat and lon) through `fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation` is an asynchronous work. that's why it provides the `addOnSuccessListener` callback.